# Multiple inheritance: calling all the overriden functions

Tags: c++, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

I have several behaviors that I want a class to have. I'd like to isolate these behaviors, so that I can reuse that code, mix and match at will.

For example, a way to do this would be:

```
class BehaviorAbstract {
  protected:
     virtual void processInfo(Info i) = 0;
}

class Behavior1: public BehaviorAbstract {
   protected:
     virtual void processInfo(Info i) { ... }
     void performBehavior1()  { ... }
}

class Behavior2: public BehaviorAbstract {
   protected:
     virtual void processInfo(Info i) { ... }
     void performBehavior2()  { ... }
}

class ConcreteObject: public Behavior1, Behavior2 {
   protected:
     void processInfo(Info i) {
       // needs to call processInfo of Behavior1 and Behavior2
       Behavior1::processInfo(i);
       Behavior2::processInfo(i);
     }
     void perform() {
       this->performBehavior1(); this->performBehavior2();
     }
 }
```

So here's the crux of the matter: `ConcreteObject` needs to call the 2 functions `processInfo` (same name, same arguments) of all the classes it inherits from. Imagine that all the behavior classes are coded by different developers. The function HAS to have the same name, because they all derive from BehaviorAbstract.

What's a reasonable design pattern to do this? I suspect multiple inheritance might be wrong here, and maybe a "multiple composition" would be better, but I need all the `Behavior` classes  and the `ConcreteObject` to derive from `BehaviorAbstract` and they all need to operate on the same protected data member of `BehaviorAbstract`.

The solution I wrote above feels wrong and ugly. Is there a way to call automatically all the parent classes that implement processInfo, without explicitely having to rewrite their name?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: warning use virtual inheritance ( `class Behavior1: virtual public BehaviorAbstract {` etc) while using multiple inheritance making a 'diamond', add missing ';', and put at minima  methods to be _protected_ rather than _private_

Comment: your code has many syntax errors and all your methods are private, but once i fix that the code seems to be fine: https://wandbox.org/permlink/9fu554mXWXrPSzcV

Comment: thanks, will fix the issues

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the question is about refactoring the ``ConcreteObject`` class to avoid using multiple inheritance... Have you tried templates? Traits or Policy?

Comment: Also I suggest you to read about the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your questions focuses on the solution you already realized that you dont like it but it is not perfectly clear what is the actual problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Thanks I will look into this. As you said, I found a solution, but it feels to me that there might be a better way to do this.

Comment: @bruno Don't make edits that change the meaning of the code.

Comment: @user463035818 you are right that I presented my half baked solution. This is because I also tried to explain my problem in words, but felt that my attempted solution would also clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynosI haven't tried templates, traits or policy. I am not sure exactly how that would work. I'll look into this.

Comment: why does `ConcreteObject` need to inherit anything? Make the methods in `Behaviour1` and `Behaviour2` public and just call them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got this right, then this question is about refactoring the `ConcreteObject` class.

**Approach #1:**

If you can make `performBehavior()` part of the `BehaviorAbstract` base class, then you can simply use a vector of `BehaviorAbstract*` and let polymorphism do its thing. I think this can be seen as the strategy pattern.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef int Info;

struct BehaviorAbstract
{
    virtual void processInfo(Info i) = 0;
    virtual void performBehavior() = 0;
};

struct Behavior1 : BehaviorAbstract 
{
     void processInfo(Info i) override
     { std::cout<< "Behavior1::processInfo()" <<std::endl; }

     void performBehavior() override
     { std::cout<< "Behavior1::performBehavior()" <<std::endl; }
};

struct Behavior2 : BehaviorAbstract
{
     void processInfo(Info i) override
     { std::cout<< "Behavior2::processInfo()" <<std::endl; }

     void performBehavior() override
     { std::cout<< "Behavior2::performBehavior()" <<std::endl; }
};

//------------------------------------------------//

struct ConcreteObject
{
    typedef std::vector<BehaviorAbstract*> vec_behavior;

    vec_behavior vba;

    ConcreteObject(vec_behavior &&v) : vba(v)
    {;}

    void processInfo(Info i)
    {
        for (auto &&itr : vba)
            itr->processInfo(i);
    }

    void perform()
    {
        for (auto &&itr : vba)
            itr->performBehavior();
    }
};

int main()
{
    ConcreteObject foo = {{new Behavior1(), new Behavior2()}};
    foo.processInfo(23);
    foo.perform();
}
```

Example: https://rextester.com/UXR42210

**Approach #2:**

Using a variadic template which creates a tuple. The iterate over that tuple and run the functions. Again, if `performBehavior1()` and `performBehavior2()` could share the same function name, then it would get easier. The extra complexity here is that you need to write a manual way of iterating over that tuple. For simplicity, I called the `processInfo()` directly from the `iterate_tuple` struct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

typedef int Info;

struct BehaviorAbstract
{
     virtual void processInfo(Info i) = 0;
};

struct Behavior1 : BehaviorAbstract 
{
     void processInfo(Info i) override
     { std::cout<< "Behavior1::processInfo()" <<std::endl; }

     void performBehavior1()
     { std::cout<< "Behavior1::performBehavior1()" <<std::endl; }
};

struct Behavior2 : BehaviorAbstract
{
     void processInfo(Info i) override
     { std::cout<< "Behavior2::processInfo()" <<std::endl; }

     void performBehavior2()
     { std::cout<< "Behavior2::performBehavior2()" <<std::endl; }
};


//------------------------------------------------//

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct iterate_tuple 
{
    static void run(T &t, Info i) 
    {
        std::get<N>(t).processInfo(i); 
        iterate_tuple<T, N-1>::run(t,i); 
    }
}; 

template<typename T>
struct iterate_tuple<T, 0> 
{
    static void run(T &t, Info i) 
    {
        std::get<0>(t).processInfo(i); 
    }
};

//------------------------------------------------//

template<typename ...T>
struct ConcreteObject
{
    std::tuple<T ...> tmp;
    static constexpr std::size_t tuple_size = std::tuple_size<decltype(tmp)>::value;

    ConcreteObject() : tmp{std::forward<T>(T()) ...}
    {;}

    void processInfo(Info i)
    {
        iterate_tuple<decltype(tmp), tuple_size-1>::run(tmp, i);
    }

    void perform()
    {
        std::get<0>(tmp).performBehavior1();
        std::get<1>(tmp).performBehavior2();
    }
};


int main()
{
    ConcreteObject<Behavior1,Behavior2> foo;
    foo.processInfo(23);
    foo.perform();
}
```

Example: https://rextester.com/SBRE16218

Both approaches avoid multiple inheritance which, from what I understood, is what you want to avoid. FYI, the simpler the better.

Comment: Thanks, this is cool. That is indeed what I was after. Strategy Pattern is interesting. The way I read it, this is simply a composition pattern, with multiple objects being composed. Is there an authoritative list of Design Patterns? When you say strategy pattern, is it something a few books would say, or something recognized industry wide?

Comment: @DevShark: Absolutely! I would recommend the following books on Design Patterns: 1) Design Patterns - Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software by Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides, 2) Game Programming Patterns by Robert Nystrom, 3) Head First Design Patterns by Eric Freeman, Elisabeth Freeman. The latter book (3) is written in Java and doesn't cover all the well-known design patterns, but it is a fun book to read and it would give you a smooth introduction to design patterns. The first book (1) is a must in your book shelf. It's like a dictionary on design patterns.